# Why is there no output in parallel assignment of h5py dataset?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, h5py

I am trying to generate an hdf5 dataset from code that runs in parallel, but when I read the dataset generated, it is blank, all entries are zero.

I have replaced the parallel code with a sequential for loop and the dataset works out fine in this case, but I don't know what is the problem with doing the same in parallel.

Here is the code to a minimal example

```py
import h5py
import scipy.stats as st

file = h5py.File('test.hdf5','a')

dset = file.create_dataset('x', (10,1024), maxshape=(None,1024), 
                           dtype='float32')

def assign(j):
    dset[j,:] = st.norm.rvs(0.,1.,1024)

from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing as mp

Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(assign)(j) for j in range(10))

file.close()
```

And the file is later read with

```py
import h5py

file = h5py.File('test.hdf5','r')
file['x'][:]
```

What is the issue with the code running in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thread of your parallel code gets it's own copy of the `dset` and they keep stepping on each other's toes. You may try something like this to get it working:

```
def get_row(x) :
    return st.norm.rvs(0.,1.,1024)

dset[:,:] = Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(get_row)(j) for j in range(10))
```

ps. thanks to @gapollo for the correction!

Comment: Your suggestion works by replacing `dset` with `dset[:,:]`

Comment: @gapolo very sorry, I haven't really tested with python myself, will make a correction